# Displaying a Json on a CollectionViewCell inside a TableViewCell. Swift 3

Tags: ios, json, swift, uitableview

I'm trying to parse a Json and display it as a collection view item which is inside a table view cell . So the hierarchy  would be like:

MainTableVIew -> TableViewCell -> CollectionView -> CollectionViewCell

So I have the json

```
"payments":[{
    "type":"card",
    "title":"Card"
}, {
    "type":"sms",
    "title":"SMS",
    "max_amount":24
},{
    "type":"account",
    "title":"Account",
    "disabled":true,
    "max_amount":-1
}]
```

which i parsed it.
The next thing which i did is in

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "NewPaymentCell") as! NewPaymentTableViewCell
            cell.package?.title = payments[indexPath.row].title
            return cell}
```

which package is

```
var package : PromoPayment? {
        didSet {
            collectionView.reloadData()
        }
    }
```

and PromoPayment the class where i get the dictionary.

In the NewPaymentCollectionView class i also populate the cell like :

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "NewPaymentCollectionCell", for: indexPath) as! NewPaymentCollectionViewCell
        cell.paymentIcon.image = UIImage(named: iconImage[indexPath.row])
        cell.kidPayment?.title = (package?.title)!
        return cell
    }
```

where kidPayment is

```
var kidPayment : PromoPayment? {
    didSet{
        namePaymentTypeLabel.text = kidPayment?.title
        }
    }
```

and it s modeled in class `NewPaymentCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell`

When i debug it returns me nil..

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one, design a custom cell of tableview and add colletion view inside it. Create an outlet for collection view and try reloading the collection view as per given code.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "NewPaymentCell") as! NewPaymentTableViewCell
            cell.package?.title = payments[indexPath.row].title
            **cell.collectionView.reloadData()**
            return cell
}
```

Instead of using a didset method use this.

Comment: Hello and thanks for your help. The thing is i have a costum cell and also a collectionView class for it which is NewPaymentCollectionView.  I tried what you said but nothing . I put a debug in  CollectionViewCell and it dosen't even get in it...

Comment: Set collection view delegate and datasource by programatically, Just before reloading the collection view.